# Jssor - is it possible to add a caption to every image in thumbnail navigator?

Tags: jssor

I would like to add caption to every image in thumbnail navigator and for the captions to scroll together with the thumbnails. Is it possible?

```
<div>
<img u="thumb" src="img/slider/02.jpg" />
<!. caption.! >
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes for sure. Thumbnail can be in html format, you can put anything in the thumbnail.

```
<div u="thumb">
<img src="img/slider/02.jpg" />
<!. caption.! >
</div>
```